# How to toggle items from one array in another

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, multidimensional-array

I have a json like:

```
"data":
    [{
        "max": 10,
        "class": "selected",
        "type": "numbers"
    }]
```

I want to use a loop, which will start from 1 and to 10 (my max value) and display all the numbers inside span like:

```
<span>1</span><span>2</span>...<span>10</span>
```

Than if I click on the span element i want this element to be added in a new empty array. So lets say I have other empty array:

```
newarray: Array<number> = []
```

Will become:

```
newarray = [1]
```

Additionally I want to toggle class when you click on the span element, taken by the json.class property.

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: It seems a requirement rather than a question.

Comment: AngularJS2 ? So do you mean AngularJS or Angular 2+ Only if it's Angular2+ tag as angular NOT AngularJS and remove 'JS' from question title. If AngularJS remove 2 from title...

Comment: do you think `gIf` is a loop?

Comment: Ok I made the edits.

Comment: You should have at least a small piece of code where you show what you've tried already. `ng-repeat`, `ng-click` should be all you need. StackOverflow is not a website where you tell your needs and we provide code. You should provide your own code, tell us what should be happening and what is currently happening, that's where we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you would use **[ngFor](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data/#conditional-display-with-ngif)** to loop through your `data` array and display the values. Then you can bind each items `(click)` handler to a function from your class and inside this function you can implement the toggle logic with pure javascript functions like checking if item is inside `newarray` with **[indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)** then if not use **[push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** to add it, otherwise you would like to remove from `newarray` with **[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)**

```
<span *ngFor="let item of data" (click)="toggle(item)">{{item.max}}</span>
```

If you want also to toggle a class selector you can do something like this:

```
<span [class]="item.currentClass" *ngFor="let item of data" (click)="toggle(item)">{{item.max}}</span>
```

and inside `toggle()` method you can just assign `item.currentClass = item.class` or `item.currentClass=''` depending on the toggle state.

See **[this demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/1eQ6GbMT5EvcPOTcw4az?p=preview)** and let me know if it is now more clear to you how to do it.

Comment: Hey, great. Yes more or less that's what I wanted to achieve. 
Only one thing , if you want to assit, was that I wanted to set the maxnumber in the array, so it will have only one object there not each one as separate. So if I set max:10, it will start from 1 and finish to 10,(something like for i=0;i<=10;i++) and I don't need to enter these numbers separately inside the data array.
I will playground a little bit more and see if I stuck more there, but yes, thank you a lot man.

Comment: @NikolaNoxiousDimitrov hey how is going, did you manage to do what you wanted to achieve ?

Comment: Thanks once again. I was busy dealing with it. I got 2 more things on this. First one, I want to stop adding the elements on the 2nd(selected) list, if it's length becomes 3. So basically to stop adding them if this list gets 3 elements (I fire alert window), but you are still able to remove elements. I tried something like while (this.slected.length <= 3) it works, but it stops the toggle() function furthermore. Second thing is that I want to remove the elements if you click on them from the 2nd(selected) list and set class to undefined or empty from 1st list.

Comment: Okay sounds as interesting task to do :), I leave you to work on that if you have big trouble just post a comment with a link to the plunker that you did and I will have a look on it.

Comment: Yes..it is. Here is the plunker :https://plnkr.co/edit/westrcj3rPfEOicU8cJ6?p=preview
I just placed function to remove from the 2nd list, and a notification when length > 3. It gives the alert, but must preserve the function from adding more elements. Also the removing elements from 2nd list, should clear the class from the first name list element. I know about e.preventDefault method, but not sure.

Comment: ok i managed the remove of style from 2nd list, and placed some simple code for max length, but I need assistance there. I am not sure should be done in the function, or outside in the DOM and use some condition in the (click) event of the element.

Comment: What you need to do else? Limit the second list to 3 items ? just put this `if(this.selected.length >= 3){        return;      }` before `this.selected.push(item);`

Comment: Great, yes thats what i needed. +5 star for you.